# Unable to save the test plan. Always showing the 'Access denied' warning. Tried to change look and feel in options. But no changes

Tags: testing, jmeter

[On click on 'Save' button, shows like this attached screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3l0d.png)

Created a HTTP request and tried to save that request. Expected to save the request. But Can't save because of access denied warning.

Used version- Apache JMeter 5.5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your user doesn't have permissions to save the file into the `C:\Windows\System32` folder, the options are in:

- either [grant your user write permissions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/give-permissions-to-files-and-folders-in-windows/78ee562c-a21f-4a32-8691-73aac1415373) to that folder
- or [run JMeter as Administrator](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-11/how-to-run-app-as-administrator-by-default-in-windows-11/m-p/3033704), in this case you will have full access to the file system
- or (better) consider using another location for your .jmx script as I don't think you should keep them inside system folders, maybe using your [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory) is better idea

Get used to take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging), normally it contains enough troubleshooting information